# Lua how do you retrieve a table row by a table value?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Example:

```
mytable = {{id=100,wordform="One Hundread"},{id=200,wordform="Two Hundread"}}
```

I want to be able to access the row based on the id to do something like this:

```
mynum = 100
print ("The value is " .. mytable[mynum].wordform)
```

The main point here is I want to be able to set the index value so I can predictably retrieve the associated value later as I might do with a java hashmap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value from the table in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078128/how-to-get-value-from-the-table-in-lua)

Comment: I reviewed that answer before posting but it still requires the index of the record assigned by Lua to retrieve the row. (Ie first record is 1, second record is 2 etc…). I want to assign my own number to retrieve the row if it’s possible in a manner similar to how hash maps work in Java

Comment: Hm I see, so from my knowledge you would have to loop through the table with if statements :b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally your table should just use the ID as key:

```lua
local mytable = {[100] = {wordform = "One hundred"}, [200] = {wordform = "Two hundred"}}
print("The value is " .. mytable[100].wordform)
```

If your table is in list form, you can convert it to ID form rather easily:

```lua
local mytable_by_id = {}
for _, item in pairs(mytable) do mytable_by_id[item.id] = item end
```

Using the hash part of a Lua table is definitely preferable over looping over the list entries in linear time as Renshaw's answer suggests (the fact that it's hidden behind a metatable may hide the poor performance and trick the reader into believing a hash indexing operation is taking place here though).

Furthermore, that answer won't even work correctly, as the list part uses integer keys as well; IDs that are valid list part indices would possibly return the wrong element. You'd have to use a function instead of a metatable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the code samples. I agree with you I should be using the ID in the index which should be performant and more than sufficient for my needs as long as I only use one key.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `metatable`

```lua
setmetatable(mytable, {__index = function(tbl, id)
    for _, item in pairs(tbl) do
      if type(item) == "table" and item.id == id then
        return item
      end
    end
end})
```

then

```
mynum = 100
print ("The value is " .. mytable[mynum].wordform) -- The value is One Hundread
```

Comment: Doesn't work: Consider `mytable = {{wordform = "two", id = 2}, {wordform = "one", id = 1}}`. `mytable[1]` will return `{wordform = "two", id = 2}` as the metamethod isn't called as the key `1` is already present (first list element). Performance is also unnecessarily bad (linear time).

Comment: thank you for pointing out my fault here. The `id` is a number, will conflict with the index.